# TinyMce create toolbar dropdown containing more toolbar items

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

This seems like it ought to be simple to do, but I'm having a hard time figuring it out.  I have a tinymce instance, and for various reasons I want to have all the toolbar items on one long line.  The problem is that there are slightly too many items for it all to fit so I'd like to create a custom button and put the toolbar items in there.  Something like:

```
tinyMCE.init({
       ...
        setup: function(editor) {
          editor.addButton('insertMenu', {
              type: 'listbox',
              text: 'Insert',
              icon: false,
              items: 'code link'
          });
        },
        toolbar1: 'insertMenu undo redo | bold italic |alignjustify | ...
```

Obviously that doesn't work because the items: 'code link' isn't correct for a listbox.. but it I'd hope it's possible to do this sort of thing in tinyMCE.  Yes I have looked at examples like http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/menu_button.php but they always contain text links etc. whereas I just want to reuse the existing toolbar icons and functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. You could use something like this if you wanted to define your button inline in the initialiser as you're doing it, or else you might be better off moving the functionality out into a separate plugin and requiring that in your initialiser. http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin

```
editor.addButton('insertMenu', function() {
        var items = [{text: 'Option 1', value: 'option1Value'}, {text: 'Option 2', value: 'option2Value'}];

        return {
            type: 'listbox',
            text: 'select box title',
            tooltip: 'a tooltip',
            values: items,
            fixedWidth: true,
            onclick: function(e) {
                console.log('Value selected: ' + e.control.settings.value)
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Hmmm.. maybe I wasn't exactly clear (or I'm just misunderstanding) what I'd like would be an example of the dropdown having the 'undo redo' icons (and associated actions) in there.  So your var items=[ 'undo', 'redo'] or similar.  What I want is to have a toolbar where some of the normal options (undo, redo, bold, italic etc.) are contained in the listbox dropdown.